# Formatting a String using String.format

Tags: java, string-formatting

I would like to format this String `010001628` to `01-162-8` using `String.format`. Can anyone help me how to achieve this?

I tried the following so far

```
String.format("%1$-2s-%1$-6s-%1$-7s", "010001628")
```

but I have difficulties to find out how to split the string with using the format expression.

Comment: Any attempts so far from your side ?

Comment: Yes, I added it to my question

Comment: @saw303 Honestly, I don't think that `String.format` is the right way to do this. I would use Regexes, or even a simple substring, as the given string value is known.

Comment: @BackSlash Thank you for your feedback. So I could substring my string in three tokens, convert them to Integers and then format them to a String. Is this a way it could work?

Comment: Why converting them to int and then rebuild a string? just build up the new string. [Demo with substring](http://ideone.com/Yl4W56) - [Demo with Regex](http://ideone.com/OeuKnw).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like

```
String in = "010001628";
String out = String.format("%s-%s-%s", in.substring(0,2), in.substring(2,7), in.substring(7,8));
```

If you don't know the length of the input string, you could replace the final substring to depend on length.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me.

Given

```
String accountNumber = "010001628";
```

Create 3 substrings and convert them to Integer. Since format is much more powerful when dealing with numbers than Strings.

```
Integer a = Integer.valueOf(accountNumber.substring(0, 2));
Integer b = Integer.valueOf(accountNumber.substring(2, 8));
Integer c = Integer.valueOf(accountNumber.substring(8));
```

then format the Integers using `String.format`

```
 String.format("%1$02d-%2$d-%3$d", a, b, c);
```

Comment: Did you see the demo I posted in comments to your question? Parsing to integer is completely useless

Comment: Sorry, my question was not clear enought. The thing is that some leading zeros have to be omitted. `010001628` needs to be `01-162-8`